# interior and closure of a set on $\mathbb{R^n}$ topology

Tags: general-topology

Hi everyone for this problem I use the $\mathbb{R}^n$ topology, I need to calculate the interior and closure of

$T=\left\lbrace(\frac{1}{n},(-1)^n):n \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$

I think this, all elements of $T$ are open sets and we know this is true $int (\frac{1}{n},(-1)^n) = (\frac{1}{n},(-1)^n)$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so we have

$int T = T $

And for the closure we $ \overline{(\frac{1}{n},(-1)^n)} = [\frac{1}{n},(-1)^n]$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in this case

$\overline{T}=\left\lbrace[\frac{1}{n},(-1)^n]:n \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$

Is this true? thx for any help

Comment: If I see $\left(\frac1n,(-1)^n\right)$, I think of it as a point of $\Bbb R^2$. Do you see it as an interval of real numbers?

Comment: Nop if $T\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ I think the $int T$ is empty and the closure is the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $T$ is a set of isolated points, and therefore $\mathring T=\emptyset$. On the other hand, $\overline T=T\cup\bigl\{(0,1),(0,-1)\bigr\}$, since the only points of $\Bbb R^2\setminus T$ which are limit of a sequence of elements of $T$ are $(0,\pm1)$.

Comment: ohh i can see now ty for the help